# Why does map not change the atom in this code?

Tags: clojure

Why doesn't the atom change?

```
(defn table-rows [data]
  (def rows (atom [:tr]))
  (map #(swap! rows conj [:td {:name %}]) data)
  @rows)

(table-rows [{:name "foo"} {:name "bar"}])
```

evaluating table-rows as shown produces:

=> [:tr]

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't change because `map` is lazy and the result is never used/realized.

Apart from this the entire approach to this code snippet is wrong. Never declare a `def` inside another `def/defn`. Use `let` instead. If you want to transform every element in a sequence `map` is the correct function to use, but skip the atom. `->>` can help to make things more readable too.

```
(defn table-rows [data]
  (->> data
       (map (fn [{:keys [name] :as row}]
              [:td {:name name}]))
       (into [:tr])))

(table-rows [{:name "foo"} {:name "bar"}])
```

As a general rule for local variable use `let`, never `def`.

```
(defn table-rows [data]
  (let [rows (for [row data]
               [:td (:name row)])]
    (into [:tr] rows)))
```

Comment: You solved another issue, too... which is elegantly handling all the keys for what will be a more complex 'table-rows' data structure.